# How to get XCOM value using api

Tags: airflow

I am trying to get [XCOM](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#concepts-xcom) value for specific DAG using API?

Can't find any way of doing it.

Any idea?!

Comment: they haven't exposed any endpoint for `XCOM`s as yet. But you can directly connect to Airflow's `SQLAlchemy` backend *meta-db* (`MySQL` / `Postgres`) and query the `xcom` table from there

Answer (score 0):

Airflow exposed API probably since version 2.

- [Airflow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html)

There is also exposed API for the **xcom** values, more details [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_xcom_entry)